# UICollectionView setLayout:animated: not preserving zIndex

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, z-index

I've noticed that when calling `setLayout:animated` in a `UICollectionView` to switch between two layouts, the currently visible cell doesn't adhere to the `zIndex` it's layout attributes has been set in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`.

For example, if I were to have a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, set it's `minimumLineSpacing` to a negative number so the cells overlap and then set a `zIndex` on each cell higher than that of the previous cell, then it appears as if the cells are stacked from the bottom up.

However this breaks if I set the layout to another layout then back to that original layout. It's as if the currently visible cell doesn't listen the zIndex and is placed atop the other cells. If I scroll the cell offscreen then back on it is in the correct place.

Answer (score 11):

I have had the same problem. Switching the layout will disregard the zIndex for the cell.

I have managed to make it "look right" by applying a translation on the z-axis like this:

```
attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, indexPath.row);
```

But it is just a visual fix, if you try to click on the item you will realize that the zIndex is still wrong until it is recycled by scrolling it offscreen.

Comment: If your answer is not an actual solution, I suggest you to post it as a comment.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am not familiar with the Stack Overflow etiquette. I am not sure how to post a comment though, all I can find is 'Add another answer'.

Comment: You are absolutly right: [adding a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) requires 50 reputation score. I didn't mean to push you. To collaborate is welcome. My comment is an invitation to collaborate in the SO way. :)

Comment: It is a solution if you use it side-by-side with zindex - ie. `attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, indexPath.row); attributes.zIndex = indexPath.row;` - at least using both worked for me.

Comment: This works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249637/14351818

Answer (score 8):

I've managed to get the behaviour I'm after by using a combination grimfrog and Charlie Elliott's responses.

Charlie Elliott's solution got the correct final outcome for the items in the collection view but there was still a snapping effect on the zIndex during the animation.

grimfrog's solution provided the correct look but had the problem of the zIndex still being incorrect after the layout change, despite looking correct.

The combination of the two, while not a great solution, does work and does use the supported transform and zIndex properties of the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

In my layout, I have

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

  [attributes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    attributes.zIndex = attributes.indexPath.item + 1;
  }];

  return attributes;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, attributes.indexPath.item);
  return attributes;
}
```

I won't make this as the correct answer just yet as I'm sure there must be another way to solve this, but I'm interested to see if this solves the problem for others as well.

Comment: This works for me, but I'm not sure why the transform3D has to be set in layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath. It does not work if it is only set in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
// In UICollectionViewCell subclass
- (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes
{
    [super applyLayoutAttributes:layoutAttributes];
    // Setting zPosition instead of relaying on
    // UICollectionView zIndex management 'fixes' the issue
    self.layer.zPosition = layoutAttributes.zIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This bit me too. After several tests I realized that `UICollectionView` will force selected cells to be on top, regardless of the z-index.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the z-index in:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath;
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)itemIndexPath;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply though I didn't have any luck with your solution. I think the issue is that UICollectionView does something with the zIndex of the selected cell. I may be wrong but changing the layout may not call the ``initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndex`` if the cell is already visible and remains visible throughout the layout change.

Comment: I just worked up a quick example of this and was able to reproduce the issues with the Z-Index. It was my understanding that `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndex` was called for every item on the screen after invalidation (animated bounds change, batch update block), but after re-reading the docs, it is for those items that need animating. 

Happily though, I was able to get consistant results when switching layouts by setting the z-index in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` instead of `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:`

Comment: @sampage can you tell me more about the z-index of selected cells? I can't find anywhere proof of what you are saying, but I do notice some inconsistencies in my animations... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using @sampage & @grimfrog answers as a starting point, I was able to get a similar situation working

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path
{
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
    attributes.zIndex = path.item;
    attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, path.item);
    // other attribute settings
    return attributes;
}
```

My `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` calls `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:` when generating the attribute array - so I only needed to include the zIndex and transform3D there.

Answer (score 0):

I got another workaround. Since all the cells belong to the same superview, calling `bringSubviewToFront :` when cell displaying works. Specifically, by looking into Debug View Hierarchy, though UICollectionViewLayout not renders cells according to zIndex, it still shows cells according to the reverse order that each subview being added to it's super view.