# UICollectionView not obeying zIndex of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The effect I'm trying to achieve is a kind of sticky header cell. It's important to me that the sticky cell floats over the top of the others. Something a bit like this:

```
┌──────────┐ 
│          │ 
│  Cell 0  │ 
│          ├┐
└┬─────────┘│
 │  Cell 4  │
 │          │
 └──────────┘
 ┌──────────┐
 │          │
 │  Cell 5  │
 │          │
 └──────────┘
 ┌──────────┐
 │          │
 │  Cell 6  │
 │          │
 └──────────┘
```

Cell 4, 5 and 6 would normally viewable and I'm constructing the attributes for cell 0 in my `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass during `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:`. All I do is call the super implementation, determine which cell I need to add in and then construct the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath:)`. I then set the `zIndex` for it to `1` (default is `0`).

The problem I'm getting is that the `UICollectionView` seems to always ignore the `zIndex`

```
┌──────────┐ 
│          │ 
│  Cell 0  │ 
│┌─────────┴┐
└┤          │
 │  Cell 4  │
 │          │
 └──────────┘
 ┌──────────┐
 │          │
 │  Cell 5  │
 │          │
 └──────────┘
 ┌──────────┐
 │          │
 │  Cell 6  │
 │          │
 └──────────┘
```

Now I believe it's possible to visually sort this out using a 3d transform, but that doesn't work for me as I don't want any taps going to the cell which is over the top. So in this example I don't want Cell 4 receiving taps intended for Cell 0.

Does anyone have any ideas? This is on iOS 8.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a standalone project in order to strip out all my extraneous code. In the process I think I found my own solution.

`override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?`
and
`override func finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath(itemIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?`

were not also applying the new `zIndex` so I think this was what was causing it.

Just thought I should post back the solution in case this comes up in a search for anyone else.

Comment: So what's the solution here? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm having this same problem and this solution doesn't work for me. When the content is initially loaded it looks fine, but after I delete a few sections, the zIndexes of my cells get all screwed up.

Comment: I think I solved it. You have to override the methods dealing with invalidation for preferred attributes to update the zIndex on the new attributes as well.

Comment: Didn't work... I wonder why. It's already been many years and Apple still hasn't addressed this issue.

Comment: @LilyBallard didn't work for me. If you have a completed solution you can post it :)

Answer (score 9):

Updating `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.zIndex` doesn't work due to UIKit bug.

This code does the trick:

```swift
// In your UICollectionViewCell subclass:
override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.apply(layoutAttributes)
    layer.zPosition = CGFloat(layoutAttributes.zIndex) // or any zIndex you want to set
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I'm wondering, is it really UIKit bug or just my own mistake? Did you see the ticket with this bug or something?

Comment: @surfrider UIKit is quite buggy place. That's one of the reasons why I switched to Flutter.

Answer (score 7):

Setting zIndex in UICollectionViewLayout didn't work for me

I set the zIndex inside the UICollectionViewController's method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
customCell.layer.zPosition = 0;
}
```

My best guess is something between the layout and the controller sets the zIndex to something weird

Comment: You are a genius Arjay!.  Thank you for posting your solution.

Comment: Better is to put this code into the UICollectionViewCell method - (void)applyLayoutAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributes (you would have to subclass UICollectionViewCell to do so).

Answer (score 3):

You need to set both values. 
The **zIndex** and the **3DTransform** Parameter.

```
class HeaderUnderCellsLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }

        attributesArray.forEach { attributes in
            if attributes.representedElementCategory == .supplementaryView && attributes.representedElementKind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
                attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, -10)
                attributes.zIndex = -200
            }
        }
        return attributesArray
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath)
        attributes?.transform3D = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, 0, -10)
        attributes?.zIndex = -200
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: transform3D set, just save my day

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is still happening on iOS 14. This is how I managed to fix it in my case:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        guard let attributes = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else
        {
            assert(false)
            return
        }
        cell.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(attributes.zIndex)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        guard let attributes = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind: elementKind, at: indexPath) else
        {
            assert(false)
            return
        }
        view.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(attributes.zIndex)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` where recording of cells didn't respect updates to `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.zIndex` but I was able to work around the issue by reloading the moved cells.

Specially I used this:

```swift
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        collectionView.moveItem(at:indexPath, to:newIndexPath)
    })

    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath, newIndexPath])
```