# How can I set different backgrounds for different sections using compositional layout?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I would like to have different backgrounds for different sections in a collection view using compositional layout.

Currently I am using `NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background` to set the background on a section. However this type of view is not dequeued or recycled the same way that a supplementary view or a cell would be. I can't make changes to it after it's initialized and I don't get to initialize it myself.

I would like to use a colour or background image that is part of the user's data that I retrieve from my back end, so the colour or image is not known to me at compile time.

**Is there any way to dynamically set the background image or colour of a section?**

Comment: Not using a compositional layout, no.

Comment: What is 'the background image or colour of a section'?  Is it the background color of cells for a given section?

Comment: No. You can use a decoration item on a section itself (`NSCollectionLayoutSection`) to provide a background for the while section

Comment: facing similar problem. Anyone found Solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much struggle, I figured out a way to do this. By itself, it's not too hacky, but requires additional hacks to work around what appears to be a UIKit bug.

### Caveats

1. This only works if the height of both your section content AND section headers are absolute and known ahead of time (at least in the section layout provider).

   This worked in my case because both my headers and cells are fixed height, and I was only using one row of horizontally-scrolling cells per section.
2. The background view must not scroll horizontally (assuming a vertically-scrolling collection view.

   In my case I wanted the section background images to be fixed, with the cells scrolling horizontally (orthogonally) over top of them.

### Constraints/Assumptions

1. We can only use compositional layout (in my case to get easy orthogonal scrolling).
2. The facility for setting a background view (mentioned in the question) won't work because **it cannot be
   configured per-section** via a supplementary view registration or any other means.
   So we must use a regular supplementary item.
3. The supplementary item must be on the section to get the right size, which
   means only using NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem.

   3.1. While it is possible to trick a different type (e.g. a non-boundary supplementary item on the group)
   into being the right size and position, using tricks results in UIKit not
   knowing when the background is actually visible, which results in flickering
   in/out during scrolling.
4. Despite being attached to the section, a section supplementary item will be
   positioned vertically **relative to the cells only**, ignoring the header part
   of the section.
5. Worse, this alignment combined with setting the height equal to total section
   height results in the supplementary item stretching the height of the section
   below the cells, making the section too tall.
6. There is a facility for setting a position offset for the supplementary item,
   however due to what I can only assume is a bug (even with an offset of 0),
   **using it causes the section header height to collapse to zero, resulting in the
   cells below moving up and and underlapping it**.

### Solution

So, to work around all of that, what I did is:

1. Set the background supplementary item size to be the known height of header + cells/row + any spacing between them.
2. Pull the background item up under the header by offsetting vertically by the
   header height (using an offset causes the cells to move up; see constraint 6).
3. Push the cells back down by padding the section insets top by the height of
   the header (`hackInsets`).
4. Pull the background's leading/trailing edges out to the view/screen edges, to
   make it full-bleed (normally it would be inset like the content). We do this by
   setting negative margins on the background image view in the background
   supplementary view registration.
5. Set a negative z-index on the background view to keep it under the cells and header.

In code, the relevant parts look like this:

```swift
let headerSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(Self.headerHeight))
let headerSupplementaryItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: headerSize, elementKind: ElementKind.header, alignment: .top)

let hackInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: Self.headerHeight, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
let backgroundHeight = MySectionHeaderView.nominalSize.height + Self.interItemSpacing + MyCollectionViewCell.nominalSize.height
let backgroundOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -MySectionHeaderView.nominalSize.height)
let backgroundAnchor = NSCollectionLayoutAnchor(edges: .top, absoluteOffset: backgroundOffset)
let backgroundSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(backgroundHeight))
let backgroundSupplementaryItem = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(layoutSize: backgroundSize, elementKind: ElementKind.background, containerAnchor: backgroundAnchor)
backgroundSupplementaryItem.zIndex = -1

let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
section.contentInsets = Self.sectionInsets.summedWith(hackInsets)
section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [headerSupplementaryItem, backgroundSupplementaryItem]
```

### iOS 17 Update

One aspect of the above technique seems to have stopped working on iOS 17 or later. UIKit seems to have changed the order that it adds supplementary views and cells to the view hierarchy, leading to the background image being on top of (and obscuring) the cells/chapters.

You'd think setting the zIndex (as we do in step 5 above) would compensate for
that, however there doesn't seem to be any value that causes the cells
to appear on top of the background supplementary view under iOS 17.

I found [a reference to this property not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57249637/203773) that predates iOS
17 but appears to be what's happening now also. We can resolve it by
setting zPosition on the CALayer of the background view as described in that answer.

This fixes the visual appearance (cells now appear on top of the background again), but the background view is still in
front in terms of tapping/interaction, so we also need to disable user
interaction on the supplementary view.

Together those two steps appear to make this a workable solution once again.

Comment: What - a - workaround. I don't have better words to appreciate this answer! I tried decorationViews and supplementaryViews by subclassing the layout class. As you mentioned there was a flickering issue. Then your answer came to me as a blessing. Worked like a charm. I hope Apple provides a way around this in the future. Thank you so much for this solution along with the explanation.

Comment: If someone can confirm this answer (@Faizyy) I'll accept it. Unfortunately I abandoned all hope of doing this months ago.

Comment: @Faizyy glad it helped!

Comment: @TylerJames I've got this solution in a shipping app now and it's been working great. Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Since the solution proposed by tfe does not work with dynamic height cells and header/footer and I needed both I had to figure out another way.

Took me a while to figure this one out but here is the way I ended up doing it.

Start by adding a NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem to your sections:

```
 let sectionBackgroundDecoration = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(
                    elementKind: "background")

section.decorationItems = [sectionBackgroundDecoration]
```

and register it on the layout like this:

```
  layout.register(SectionBackgroundDecorationView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: "background")
```

Then in the SectionBackgroundDecorationView override apply like this:

```
    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {

   // Customize using the IndexPath or by pasing custom layout attributes...

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did.

I had a complicated layout where I needed to change the look of the section decoration in some cases.

By implementing:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplaySupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and then casting the view to be displayed as my decoration view and referencing the indexPath, I was able to determine if the decoration was the one I needed to modify. I then updated a var on the decoration view and it took care of updating itself.